# ColdFusion/SQL : ELEMENT XXX IS NOT DEFINED IN FORM

Tags: html, sql, forms, coldfusion

I have a form on my cfm page, that is to insert a new row into an SQL datasource.  The cfm page hosts the form - and when submitted the -action.cfm page inserts the data and relocates the user to a page listing the new information.  The problem I am getting is when I submit the form I am getting:: Element NEWUSERID is undefined in FORM.

the form on the insertScores.cfm page:

```
<form method="post" action="insertScores-action.cfm">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>User ID</td>
    <td><input name="newUserID" type = "text" size = "50"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input name="newFirstName" type="text" size="50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input name="newLastName" type="text" size="50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input name="newEmailAdd" type="text" size="50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td><input name="newScore" type="text" size="50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pass Date</td>
    <td><input name="newPassDate" type="text" size="50" value="dd/mm/yyyy"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Level</td>
    <td><input name="newLevel" type="text" size="50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Insert Scores"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

The insertScores-action.cfm page

```
<cfquery name="insertScores" datasource="staffwrite">
INSERT INTO protinfo_scores (
  userID
  , first_name
  , last_name
  , email
  , curr_score
  , curr_score_date
  , level
  )
VALUES (
    '#form.newUserID#'
  , '#form.newFirstName#'
  , '#form.newLastName#'
  , '#form.newEmailAdd#'
  , '#form.newScore#'
  , '#form.newPassDate#'
  , '#form.newLevel#'
  )
</cfquery>


<cfquery name = "queryScore" datasource="staff">
  SELECT userid, level
  FROM protinfo_scores
  WHERE userid LIKE '#form.newUserid#'
  AND level = '#form.newLevel#'
</cfquery>

<cflocation URL="newScore.cfm?userid=#url.userid#&level=#url.level#">
```

newScore.cfm

```
<center>
  <h2>Your ammendments have been made.</h2><hr>
</center>

<cfquery name = "queryScore" datasource="staff">
  SELECT first_name, last_name, email, curr_score, curr_score_date, userid, level
  FROM protinfo_scores
  WHERE userid LIKE '#URL.userid#'
  AND level = #URL.level#
</cfquery>


<cfoutput query="queryScore">

<table>
  <tr bgcolor=beige>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td width="40">#queryScore.first_name# #queryScore.last_name#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td width="40">#queryScore.email#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor=beige>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td width="100">#queryScore.userid#</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Level</td>
    <td width="100">#queryScore.level#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor=beige>
    <td>Current Score</td>
    <td width="40">#queryScore.curr_score#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date Passed</td>
    <td width="40">#queryScore.curr_Score_date#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You should really use `<cfqueryparam>` on all your queries, to prevent SQL injection

Comment: I've read your code a couple of times and cannot see anything obviously wrong. Two questions though: What happens when you put a `<cfdump var="#form#> <cfabort>` at the top of insertScores-action.cfm and what is in newScore.cfm? It's unlikely, but could you be getting that far then erroring there instead?

Comment: What do you get if you dump out the whole form scope at the top of your insertScores-application.cfm page?

Comment: Are insertScores-action.cfm and insertScores-application.cfm really two separate pages?  Look at your form action attribute and the name of the action page you described.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `queryScore` query in  insertScores-action.cfm?  You do a cflocation immediately afterwards without referencing anything from that query. Which won't be the cause of your error, but it's good to eliminate confusion

Comment: duncan - the purpose of queryScore is to re-query the table to get the relevant information out to pass via the URL variable.

Answer (score 1):

> and when submitted the -action.cfm page inserts the data and relocates
>   the user to a page listing the new information

I can't tell from the wording if this is the desired effect or the actual effect.  If it is the actual effect, your error is occurring on `newScore.cfm` which would make sense because the data in the form scope does not persist after the `cflocation` and you're trying to use `form.newUserID` after the output table..

If this is the desired effect and NOT the actual effect...

1. As Dan said, you're looking at two different files.  You show code from `insertScores-application.cfm` but your action is pointing to `insertScores-action.cfm`.
2. The code in your question is not exact copy/paste or even all of your code (you're missing a `</form>` tag to say the least).  In this case I'd suggest showing us the actual code AND the error message. Many times I see `element XXX is undefined in FROM` (notice it says FROM and not FORM, something easy to miss when you're staring at the same thing for hours).  The error message will tell you what line number the error is on.  Is the line number actually among the code you posted?

Comment: the FORM dump doesnt seem to dump anything.  Also, I have edited the Q to include the newScore.cfm, and its -action not -application  ,  that was me getting a tad confuzled.  Also, the first snippet is just a snippet of the relevant code, and there should be (and is) a </form> tag immediately after the table.

Comment: can you show the full error?  screen shot or copy/paste everything in the gray box.  It should include, the error, the file name, row number, and surrounding code around the error (assuming robust exception information is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `<form></form>` to a `<cfform></cfform>` and all now appears to work swimmingly.  I was under the impression this would not make any difference but clearly it does.